# How can I define metafont functions in one file to avoid redefining them each time I make a new file?

Tags: macros, graphics, metapost, includegraphics, multiple-files

I have a metafont diagram that is generated by calling 4 functions that I know I will use multiple times with different parameters.

To avoid copy pasting like a madman, I'd like to have these function in their own file and include them only in a tex file if relevant or necessary.

However, right now I don't even know how to make them their own command, let alone including them from other files:

Result:

[image]

code:

```
\documentclass[border=10cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{luamplib}
\mplibnumbersystem{double}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
{\centering
\begin{mplibcode}
u:=1cm;

% Draw a lattice layer upside down
% parameters are: horizontal offset, level (height), thickness of % the lines, color of the lines
vardef inverted_layer(expr n,l,s,c)= 
     %declare variables
    save parent, lc, rc; 
    pair parent, lc, rc;  
    parent:=(n, l);
    % assign values of left and child nodes, forming a 'v' pattern
    lc :=  (n-1, l+1);
    rc :=  (n+1, l+1);
    draw u*parent--u*rc withpen pencircle scaled s withcolor c;
    draw u*parent--u*lc withpen pencircle scaled s withcolor c;
enddef;

% Draw and inverted lattice
% parameters are: horizontal offset, number of layers, thickness
% of the lines, color of the lines
vardef inverted_lattice(expr n,l, size, color)=
    for i=0 upto l:
        for j=0 upto i:
            inverted_layer((j + n)*2 - i, i-(l+1), size, color);
        endfor;
    endfor;
enddef;

% Similar as above except the lattice isn;t upside down
vardef layer(expr n,l,s,c)=
    save parent, lc, rc;  
    pair parent, lc, rc;  
    parent:=(n, l);
    lc :=  (n-1, l-1);
    rc :=  (n+1, l-1);
    draw u*parent--u*rc withpen pencircle scaled s withcolor c;
    draw u*parent--u*lc withpen pencircle scaled s withcolor c;
enddef;

vardef lattice(expr n,l, size, color)=
for i=0 upto l:
    for j=0 upto i:
            layer((j + n)*2 - i, -i, size, color);
        endfor;
    endfor;
enddef;

% Start figure
beginfig(0);
% Create labels for the bottom level
for i=-3 upto 7:
    save j;
    numeric j;
    j := i - 2;
    % No plus symbol for egatives
    if j<0:
        label.top(textext("\huge$K_{i"& decimal j &"}$"), (i*u*2 + 1*u,-6*u));
    % no arithmetic symbols for 0
    elseif j=0:
        label.top(textext("\huge$K_{i}$"), (i*u*2+1*u,-6*u));
    % regular labeling
    else:
        label.top(textext("\huge$K_{i+"& decimal j &"}$"), (i*u*2+1*u,-6*u));
    fi
endfor;
for i=0 upto 5:
    %create labels for the top level 
    if i-3<0:
        label.top(textext("\huge$C_{i"& decimal(i-3)&"}$"), (i*u*2,0));
    elseif i-3=0:   
        label.top(textext("\huge$C_{i}$"), (i*u*2,0));
    else:
        label.top(textext("\huge$C_{i+"& decimal(i-3) &"}$"), (i*u*2,0));
    fi
    % draw 5 regular lattices in black at different offsets
    % so that they partially overlap
    lattice(i,4,1, black);
endfor;

% draw the inverted red lattice with thick lines
inverted_lattice(2.5,4,3, red);

z0=u*(2,0);
z1=u*(3,-1);
z2=u*(2,-2);
z3=u*(1,-3);
z4=u*(0,-4);
z5=u*(1,-5);
z6=u*(2,-6);

% draw the blue path
draw z0--z1--z2--z3--z4--z5--z6 withpen pencircle scaled 3bp withcolor blue;
for i=0 upto 6:
    fill fullcircle scaled 4bp shifted z[i];
endfor;
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\par}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using an `input` command, i.e. `input myfilewithmymacros.mp;` at the start of the `mplibcode` environment in which you would like them available.  If you will be doing so often, then you can use the `\everymplib` command (as below) to input the file at the start of every `mplibcode` environment.  I also enabled `textext` labels, so that the `\textext` command isn't required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{makogandefs.mp}
% Draw a lattice layer upside down
% parameters are: horizontal offset, level (height), thickness of % the lines, color of the lines
vardef inverted_layer(expr n,l,s,c)= 
     %declare variables
    save parent, lc, rc; 
    pair parent, lc, rc;  
    parent:=(n, l);
    % assign values of left and child nodes, forming a 'v' pattern
    lc :=  (n-1, l+1);
    rc :=  (n+1, l+1);
    draw u*parent--u*rc withpen pencircle scaled s withcolor c;
    draw u*parent--u*lc withpen pencircle scaled s withcolor c;
enddef;

% Draw and inverted lattice
% parameters are: horizontal offset, number of layers, thickness
% of the lines, color of the lines
vardef inverted_lattice(expr n,l, size, color)=
    for i=0 upto l:
        for j=0 upto i:
            inverted_layer((j + n)*2 - i, i-(l+1), size, color);
        endfor;
    endfor;
enddef;

% Similar as above except the lattice isn;t upside down
vardef layer(expr n,l,s,c)=
    save parent, lc, rc;  
    pair parent, lc, rc;  
    parent:=(n, l);
    lc :=  (n-1, l-1);
    rc :=  (n+1, l-1);
    draw u*parent--u*rc withpen pencircle scaled s withcolor c;
    draw u*parent--u*lc withpen pencircle scaled s withcolor c;
enddef;

vardef lattice(expr n,l, size, color)=
for i=0 upto l:
    for j=0 upto i:
            layer((j + n)*2 - i, -i, size, color);
        endfor;
    endfor;
enddef;
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{luamplib}
    \everymplib{input makogandefs.mp;}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}
% Start figure

beginfig(0);
u:=1cm;
% Create labels for the bottom level
for i=-3 upto 7:
    save j;
    numeric j;
    j := i - 2;
    % No plus symbol for egatives
    if j<0:
        label.top("\huge$K_{i"& decimal j &"}$", (i*u*2 + 1*u,-6*u));
    % no arithmetic symbols for 0
    elseif j=0:
        label.top("\huge$K_{i}$", (i*u*2+1*u,-6*u));
    % regular labeling
    else:
        label.top("\huge$K_{i+"& decimal j &"}$", (i*u*2+1*u,-6*u));
    fi
endfor;
for i=0 upto 5:
    %create labels for the top level 
    if i-3<0:
        label.top("\huge$C_{i"& decimal(i-3)&"}$", (i*u*2,0));
    elseif i-3=0:   
        label.top("\huge$C_{i}$", (i*u*2,0));
    else:
        label.top("\huge$C_{i+"& decimal(i-3) &"}$", (i*u*2,0));
    fi
    % draw 5 regular lattices in black at different offsets
    % so that they partially overlap
    lattice(i,4,1, black);
endfor;

% draw the inverted red lattice with thick lines
inverted_lattice(2.5,4,3, red);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

Once you have compiled the above, try the following document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luamplib}
    \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}

\begin{mplibcode}
input makogandefs.mp;

beginfig(0);
u:=1cm;
inverted_lattice(2.5,4,3, red);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

If you get tired of typing `input makogandefs.mp;` at the start of each `mplibcode` block, then the `\everymplib` command can be used as above and it will be inserted automatically.

Comment: Sorry I am still a bit confused, I create a blank file with the .mp extension. Say I want the 4 functions, lattice, layer, inverted lattice and inverted layer to be available in that file.

How do I define them such that they can be called from not_the_definitions.tex ?

Comment: The file with the `.mp` extension holds the macros that you would like to be available in the `mplibcode` environments in your main document.  When you want those macros available within an `mplibcode` environment, then you would use `\begin{mplibcode} input makogandefs.mp; **do stuff** \end{mplibcode}`.  If you compiled the code above, then `makogandefs.mp` should exist in your compilation directory, in that case then you can delete the `filecontents` environment and recompile.

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and mark this as the solution as soon as I get it working. Thank you